# How to iterate array forever until break statement using while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, iterator, buffer

I want to iterate buffered array/list until break statement executes in while loop.
And if buffer is empty or when reaches max, reload the buffer.

```
buffered_array[]
while (buffered_array.hasNext){
  if(condition){
     break;
  }
  // statements here...
  if (buffered_array.last or equals to max){
     // reload buffered_array
  }
}
```

What is the best method to do it??

Answer (score 2):

put your while in a infinite `loop` , once the inner loop is finish (reached the end ) then again reinitialize the array to the beginning ,in next iteration of the `outter loop`

```
buffered_array[]
   while(true){
   buffered_array[] =.....; // set to beginning/reload 
   while (buffered_array.hasNext){
     if(condition){
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

but you need to break your outter loop at some point in your code so either you can have a `boolean` variable as `true` and later you can set it to `false` or have an `if` condition to break it

```
buffered_array[]
   boolean flag=true;  // either set it to false somewhere in you loop
   while(flag){
   buffered_array[] =.....; // set to beginning/reload 
   while (buffered_array.hasNext){
     if(condition){ 
        break;
      }
   }
   if(condition){break; or flag=false;} // or break the outter loop with some condition
}
```